# how do i access contour sequentially in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am segmenting a handwritten word using contours in opencv (cpp). But after segmenting is gives random output contour.It is not gives as left to right ordering of word.Help me to obtain order.

Comment: could you clarify your question? at least attach an image about the segmentation's result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have something like the following to extract the contours:

```
// Contros found from input array
cv::Mat _src = src.getMat();
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(_src, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,
        params.contourDetMethod);
```

You can iterate through your contours (here `contors`) and create bounding boxes using `cv::boundingRect`. Now you can use coordination of the resulting [`Rect`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect) with others and find out their spatial order.

Comment: @xyz if the answer is helping, you can mark it as the correcr answer.